# How to handle schema errors in rapidjson?

Tags: jsonschema, rapidjson

How can I detect the following error situation:
A `rapidjson::SchemaDocument` is constructed from a `rapidjson::Document`, but the JSON contained in that `Document` is no proper schema; for example,
`{ "type": "object", "properties": [1] }`.
Currently, all I get is an access violation when I validate a document against this faulty schema.

Thanks
Hans

Comment: Why not validate the schema first using the meta-schema? Implementations usually have those built in, and sometimes provide a function to do the work.

Comment: @Relequestual, I had thought about that, but how can I be sure that the metaschema matches the implementation in rapidjson?